# How to automatically clear history on Safari 5 when quitting?

Tags: mac, safari, privacy

I wonder if there is a way to ask Safari to clear history when it quits. The shortest setting of this privacy preferences seems to be "keep only the last day". I think it's not enough for privacy matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this not exactly the answer to my actual question, but that's what I wanted to find : no history stored on my computer. Actually, there is a item in the Main Safari Menu named "Private Browsing" that can be checked, and do the job. Nothing is stored nor left on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no built-in way to do that. There is a post on [PC World Wiki](http://wiki.pcworld.com/index.php/Clearing_Safari%27s_History_Automatically_at_Logoff) which gives a Bash script for clearing Safari's history automatically at logoff.

Comment: Is it always a little weird to select an "AFAIK, No" as the answer to a question, but I'll do it if there is no better answer ;-)